# How to install/use cx_Oracle in PyPy

Tags: python, cx-oracle, pypy

I can't seem to find anything on Google or SO with information on getting cx_Oracle to work with PyPy. Can somebody please tell me if it's possible, and if so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PyPy actually has it's own cx_Oracle module, you need to compile it yourself though, which looks like:

```
./pypy/translator/goal/translate.py pypy/translator/goal/targetpypystandalone.py --withmod-oracle
```

Comment: Is there documentation of this somewhere?

Comment: This is not a good solution as this option is no longer supported (probably that's the reason you can't find it in documentation). It works, but it installs cx_Oracle 5.0.0 which is very old and probably incompatible with the rest of stuff you are trying to use.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours spent on investigating different solutions, I sorted out that only this one is stable enough: use cx_oracle_on_types: https://github.com/lameiro/cx_oracle_on_ctypes